# How to use urllib2 and urllib in python to make a script that automatically login into my wordpress blog?

Tags: python, http

I'm learning to use urllib2 and urllib.And I wrote the same script according to the given example at http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html . But it seems doesn't work.Something response is the source code of the login page!And I used the firebug to check if the same source code is returned,the answer is yes!But i can still login into my blog on my browser!What kind of knowledge do I need to know? Http? or ......

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
import urllib

url='http://www.mywordpressblog.com/wp-login.php'
values={'log':'my login name',
        'pwd':'my password'}
data=urllib.urlencode(values)
req=urllib2.Request(url,data)
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page=response.read()
print the_page
```

Comment: I've found it much easier to use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to automate dealing with web forms.

Comment: Use `live http header` addon and check what all headers are send by your browser while performing the login and than try to send those headers through your python script. Your code is certainly missing `User-Agent` header and may be `Referer` header. Take a look at (urllib2.Request)[docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request] on how to send http-headers with urllib2 and python.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this principle works for Wordpress, but to augment your code with basic http authentication, you should:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import base64


USERNAME="user"
PASSWORD="password"

url='http://www.mywordpressblog.com/wp-login.php'
req = urllib2.Request(url)

# create http header with base64 encoded user and password
base64string = base64.encodestring(
    '%s:%s' % (USERNAME, PASSWORD))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", authheader)

response =urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page=response.read()
print the_page
```

To get more information, please check [Basic Authentication Tutorial](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml)

**UPDATE**

You should issue https `POST` request with header fields with `User-Agent` emulating one of browsers and urlencoded credentials as provided below:

```
import urllib2
import urllib


url='https://en.wordpress.com/wp-login.php'

headers = [
  ("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5")]

data = [
    ("log","YOURNAME"), 
    ("pwd","YOURPASSWORD"), 
    ("testcookie",1), 
    ("submit","Log In"), 
    ("redirect_to","http://wordpress.com/"), 
    ("rememberme","forewer")]

req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(dict(data)), dict(headers))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

the_page=response.read()
print the_page
```

Comment: This method can be used to login into my router,but the wordpress blog is still can not be logined with it!Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You must use HTTPBasicAuthHandler for login into your blog. See docs at "Basic Authentication" section.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

```
data = {'username': 'foo', 'password': 'secret'}
url = 'http://www.example.com/'
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```